# Determine the terminal value of y using a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Rolling summation.

Determine the terminal value of `y`. While `y` is less than the threshold, add  `0.01*(−2)` to the old value of `y`.

```
y = 0.1 
threshold = .11
```

I tried this.

```
while  y < threshold:
    if True: 
        print(y+ 0.01*(y-y**2))
    else:
        break
```

Why did nothing run when i tried this?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether, by `0.01(y-y²)` you mean `0.01*(y-y**2)`? Additionally, nothing happens inside your while loop currently to modify the value of y - so if the while loop is set to run as long as y is less than the threshold, the while loop will never end. Additionally, `if True` will always evaluate to `True`, because `True` will always evaluate to `True`. Can you clarify your intention for this code please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic] and how to create a [mre]. Please explain what you mean by "Why did nothing run when I tried this?" If you really left the `:` out after the `while` condition, then that's the problem. Otherwise, this code should have generated a `TypeError` because of `0.01(y-y^2)`. Please note that `^` is not exponentiation in Python, it is the bitwise XOR operator. There are many issues with this code and it's difficult to help while it's improperly formatted and contains syntax errors.

Comment: yes @Vin I am trying to raise it to the second power. When I put your code into python nothing happens when I press run. Why is that?

Comment: @sofiequallsissocool Is your python setup working correctly? For instance if you just run `print ('hello world')` does anything happen?

Comment: @sofiequallsissocool then I'm not sure what the issue is - when I run my code, I get `0.11030230740072473` printed to console - which is what I would expect - not sure why the same isn't happening for you...

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to start with `y = 0.1`, and then continuously update `y` by adding the value of `0.01*(y-y**2)` to the current value of y until it equals or exceeds the value of `threshold = 0.11`, the following code accomplishes this. If your intent is otherwise, please specify.

```
y = 0.1
threshold = .11

while y < threshold:
    y += 0.01*(y-y**2)

print(y)
```